# Accessing id of dynamic x3d inline element

Tags: javascript, x3d

I am trying to access x3d nodes with javascript. I am adding further x3d elements with the following code:

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
inline = document.createElement('inline');
inline.setAttribute('nameSpaceName', 'myX3d');
inline.setAttribute('url', '1_2__0_elem.x3d');
inline.setAttribute('mapDEFToID', 'true');
inline.setAttribute('render', 'true');
inline.setAttribute('load', 'true');
scene.appendChild(inline);
```

The elements get displays and it works fine. But now I want to change the attributes inside 1_2__0_elem.x3d, but I always get null as return value of document.getElementById("myX3d__inner"). It works when I am adding it without javascript. Is there a way to access the id of dynamic elements with js?

Thanks in advance, clax

Comment: Are you setting the `id` correctly? I don't see an `inline.setAttribute('id', 'inner')`... You might also be trying to access the element before its been initialized. Try `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(document.getElementById("myX3d__inner")); }, 1000);` to see if it's beacuse you just need to wait for the element to be initialized.

Comment: yes the id was set correctly. Thanks a lot for your comment. The reason why it didn't work was that the loading process of the x3d file has not been finished as i tried to access the elements immediately after my code above. I found an alternative solution, which you can see below. thanks, greets clax

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to solve my problem (access during render time with javascript). I used php to write all files of interest in the main x3d file. I set the render tag "false" and the load tag "true". On client side the attribute render tag gets changed to "true" by an user request. If too many files are inside the main .x3d file load can be set to false or can be deleted by php.